# exec proxy not found for NativePageTransitions

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

i already add the plugin with cli
[github.com](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions).

and this my code

```
 <button onclick="slide('right', 'dashboard.html')">back</button>


 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function slide(direction,href) {
      window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide(
      {
        'duration': 400,
        'direction': direction,
        'iosdelay': 50,
        'androiddelay': 120,
        'winphonedelay':800,
        'href': href
      },
      function () {
        console.log('slide transition finished');
      });
    }

</script>
```

and also i already add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

this my complete code 
[pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/raw/WGbqE5xH)

but is not working, i have error on console 
**exec proxy not found for NativePageTransitions**

Answer (score 0):

In JS you only have a 1:

```
function slide(href)
```

but in your html you have 2:

```
slide('right', 'dashboard.html')
```

Comment: still not working, i add two parameter in my javascript and html